# Grouping repos on GitHub?

Tags: github

Here's the situation: I'm migrating a bunch of repos to github. The repos are currently organized into groups/directories like 'stack', 'websites', 'applications', etc.

There's no way (I've found) to create groups or folders on GitHub for repos, except with organizations, which seems a poor choice. But maybe not? The problem here is that some of the groups are very small, while others are large... with sub-groups, and I'd like to keep all the projects in one root bucket.

So, I'm left with maybe using a naming convention. Like: 'stack-apache', 'website-foo.com', 'application-some-project'. Or just giving up on organizing them in github and let the project pages / website handle the organization.

Re. scale, I'm looking at 20+ repos initially, with new repos added over time at an estimated rate of 2-5 /year for the next few years.

Anyone have experience with this kind of thing?

Comment: Meta observation: I'm pretty sure searched for answers when I posted the question (because I always do). Likely I never used the term 'folders'. It is, of course, mostly a duplicate. Also, brings to mind something I once heard about the difference between "movies" and "cinema". They're synonyms, but not the same. Different cultural groups use them in different ways. This makes me think of the positive aspect of duplicates in that they make things findable because it's putting out a slightly different take/way of thinking/perspective.

Comment: Yes, that is the primary reason why duplicates are usually still accessible and readable on SO.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The idea really is to use organizations to group your related repo together. This also makes it easier for your team member to filter their activity feeds to only organizations they're interested into.

This is like that on Github as `git` is repo based, not file system based like SVN.

Maybe "Organization" is not a very intuitive name, but on alternative Git platform like Gitlab, these divisions are named "group". You should really consider them like that.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I originally had 'Or maybe "Organization" is a misleading name?' in the post, but cut for brevity. I think I'm going to go  with core projects under the company-Organization and create a few group-Organizations for organizing related projects.

Comment: I'd argue that treating GitHub organizations as groups complicates billing and permissions and fragments management. GitHub simply does not have a concept of related repositories without imposing additional semantics. Prefixing repository names is the most common practice I've seen.

Comment: Good point re. billing. Unstated, the original question was for fundamentally open source projects, so billing wasn't an issue. My feeling is that the 'teams' is sufficient to organize permissions, so in an open source context, this works. In a closed source context, I agree re. prefixing.

Comment: the unfortunate addition to this is that whilst organisations are the way to create this. They exist as a top level entity. So I can't create an organisation inside my account so it appears like a group, they attach directly to the github.com top level namespace :(

Comment: Yes, Agree here. Organizations will work more closely to a "group" of projects. It will also have a different unique path which might be close to a new directory for repos. Unfortunately it will be one level only, no nested subgroups or "sub-organizations" can be created.

Answer (score 58):

### Update 2024

There (still) isn't a concrete way of grouping in Github.

Instead, I use an [Organization profile readme](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/customizing-your-organizations-profile) and manually group relevant repos.

Its not ideal, and its manual, but it gives me full control - including linking down to common items like Actions.

[image]

---

### Update 2023

Github added the lists-feature (still in beta).
If you star a repository you can add it to an existing list or create a new one.
Still not a very intuitive way to group your own repositories but it works.

[image: starred lists]

---

### Update 2020

I'm not sure exactly when, but Github has (somewhat recently) added the concept of projects, which kind of fill the missing gap. I would argue they aren't quite the same as Bitbucket Projects but they are better suited to grouping related repo's in Github than Orgs

[image]

---

### Original answer

Organisations in my opinion fit a different purpose in Github than grouping repos (although they do serve to group repos). Organisations are more about fine grained control around repo access (thats my understanding).

Bitbucket has introduced the concept of "Projects", with the following hierarchy (with a comparison to Github):

```
Bitbucket: Team         -> has N -> Projects -> has N -> Repos
Github:    Organisation -> has N                      -> Repos
```

Bitbucket still allows Repos to **not** be assigned to an team or project, I am guessing to support older repos that existed before the concept of a project.

To answer the question, no, not directly. There are outstanding requests with Github to add groups, but it doesn't seem likely (at this point in time).

Prefixing works as a so-so solution:

Repo name: `[project]__[repo name]`

Lets say you have a client "acme" with two repos:

Eg: `acme__api`
Eg: `acme__landing`

Github's search is quick and inline, so doing a search for `acme__` in your repo list will list all repos for the `acme__` project.

Comment: The one big problem on the github for me was losing everything assigned to a repository after delete a repository. Yes, forks will be lost because of hashes in the git, but what about all other stuff? It's quite very annoying when you use github only as a mirror and lose all related data when recreate a repository from another storage.

Comment: GitHub projects are more to manage workflow in a kanban style way, not to group repos like GitLab does.

Comment: @mcamurri Agree 100%. It "kind of fills the missing gap"

Comment: It still doesn't enable me, as a user, to group repos that aren't mine for purposes of organization and separation - repos of e.g frameworks, or tools

Comment: @GalGrünfeld Agreed - its still not a fully solved problem at the Github end

Comment: Can you put the updated part in the beginning of this comment?

Comment: @Saba I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: Its important to highlight that "lists" aren't private. Private repo' aren't visible, but if you are using it for clients, for example, "Client ACME", everyone will be able to see you are working with Client ACME

Comment: Projects and lists are not designed to actually group projects. Lists are only visual, available to the user, works more like a filter, while projects are for kanban workflows style, is not possible to add a repository into a project, just manage it's issues.

Comment: @isca I agree, but my suggestions are alternatives because Github lacks a feature to do it correctly. It doesn't come close to the structure available in Gitlab.

Answer (score 7):

I think, the idea to group repos on the github is that just put a delimiter between items you want to be related to each other. For example, "project1_projectA_projectX", or "project1-projectA-projectX", or even "project1--projectA--projectX".

For myself I prefer the double-dash delimiter as more intuitive for replacement of the slash character delimiter (/) and less usable in a standalone repository name.

Then the list of your planning projects you have to create would be:

- project1
- project1--projectA
- project1--projectA--projectX

As soon as you create a repository with a delimeter (_ or -) in your name, there is won't be an option to set, for example, the repo description or license from the repo title page. You have to handle these from the repository title page after a first push has made. But you can leave it simple, for example, for the projectX it would be something like this: "project1--projectA submodule".